# C# - double-Value transmitted to Java client via byte[]

Tags: java, c#, double, mqtt, transmission

I am transmitting a double value from a C#-mqtt client to a Java-mqtt client. Mqtt requires its payload to be a byte[] so I in c# I am doing the following:

```
byte[] vals = BitConverter.GetBytes(sub.value); // c#-sender
```

and transmitting this over mqtt to a java client, which in turn

```
double result = ByteBuffer.wrap(vals).getDouble(); // java-receiver
```

However, while the original double-value is in the range of ~1 to 10, the resulting java value is in the range of 10^-311 to 10^-312.

I am not very familiar with c# at this point and can't find the problem.

Is it an offset problem? LE/BE ? I am pretty much stuck and would love if you could give me a hint.

Comment: Don't know about C#, but you can use [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) and suitable printing to visualize the bits of the `double`; might help you to pin down whether endianness is the issue.

Comment: Java ByteBuffer also has the `order(ByteOrder or)` method which can be used to flip the order, it should be a one line insert to test if it's a ordering problem

Comment: hardillb hah! thanks for the tip. .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) did the trick! Can you add an answer?

Comment: @Aeefire answer added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, try flipping the byte order on the ByteBuffer using the `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder)` method